# GETDATE month in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, datepart

I have this table:

| Key_No | Import_Date |
| --- | --- |
| 12345678 | 2023-09-01 |
| 98765432 | 2023-10-01 |
| 85231654 | 2023-11-01 |
| 00020102 | 2023-12-01 |

I want to find the data of `import_date` after this month.

I tried a SQL statement like this:

```
select * 
from Table1 
where DATEPART(mm, Import_date) = MONTH(GETDATE()) 
  and DATEPART(yyyy, import_date) = YEAR(GETDATE())
```

But I can only find the data for October. I need to show all data after the current month.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, two things are important here:

1. We can simply use the function `EOMONTH` which returns the last day of the current month.
2. We should **avoid to use functions in the `WHERE` clause**. They will be called for every single row of the table and will likely slow down the query, escpecially when the table has many rows. We will do better to just declare a variable with the date. Then we check if the date from the table is later than this date or not. Thus, a function is executed once only and not a thousand times or even a million times.

So if the current month should not be included and we want to start with the first day of the next month, we can do this:

```
DECLARE @compareDate DATE
SET @compareDate = EOMONTH(GETDATE())
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE
  Import_Date > @compareDate
```

If also the current month should be included, this will do:

```
DECLARE @compareDate DATE
SET @compareDate = DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-1))
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE
  Import_Date >= @compareDate
```

Try out with some sample data [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/G6GARk3Y)

I recommend to read this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) that explains both the function `EOMONTH` and how to use a variable.

Comment: And to make it a single statement (for a view for example) wrap the DECLARE into a CTE pre-statement to avoid writing a procedure.

Comment: Actually using a function in the where clause would be fine here because you are doing it with a scalar value. The performance problem arises when the function takes in an argument from the row. Regardless this is the right way to handle this type of data comparison.

Comment: @SeanLange You're generally right. I was talking about the queries the OP showed in their question. There, the functions will likely cause bad performance.